# Select only row columns with values not equal to

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I wonder if it is possible with MySQL. I output the result of my "select" query. The result is always one single row. What I want is to output only columns with values not equal to 0. I do not want the user to see everything because lots of columns in the row are 0 and thus not interesting for him.

Example row:

column name:  a b c d e f

column value: 1 6 0 6 7 0

I do not want columns c and f to appear in the result.

Can that be achieved in SQL resp. MySQL? Or do I have to perform additional processing of SQL result with some programming language like PHP?

Best regards

Ewgenij

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: So, if you're only returning one row, and that row has 0's in some of the columns, you don't want to show that row?  Please elaborate on your question, and also post an example of what you've setup and tried.

Comment: Hello, I added an example to my question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have dynamic columns with a static query.

The only way to have dynamic columns in MySQL is with a stored procedure (which will have to build a query as a string and run it).